# How to increment a column based off the value in the previous row while using groupby in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
claim   diagnosis   sequence
100     1           1.0
100     2           1.0
100     3           NaN
100     4           NaN
105     1           1.0
105     2           2.0
105     3           2.0
105     4           NaN
111     1           1.0
111     2           2.0
111     3           3.0
111     4           NaN
```

What I need is to have all the NaNs be replaced by the oneup value in the previous row, by claim:

```
claim   diagnosis   sequence
100     1           1.0
100     2           1.0
100     3           2.0
100     4           3.0
105     1           1.0
105     2           2.0
105     3           2.0
105     4           3.0
111     1           1.0
111     2           2.0
111     3           3.0
111     4           4.0
```

I've tried cumcount, but can't seem to get it to use the previous value.  I've also tried loc, but also don't quite have the hang of it yet.

```
things = [{'claim':100, 'diagnosis':1, 'sequence':1},
    {'claim':100, 'diagnosis':2, 'sequence':1 },
    {'claim':100, 'diagnosis':3, },
    {'claim':100, 'diagnosis':4, },
    {'claim':105, 'diagnosis':1, 'sequence':1},
    {'claim':105, 'diagnosis':2, 'sequence':2},
    {'claim':105, 'diagnosis':3,'sequence':2 },
    {'claim':105, 'diagnosis':4, },
    {'claim':111, 'diagnosis':1, 'sequence':1},
    {'claim':111, 'diagnosis':2, 'sequence':2},
    {'claim':111, 'diagnosis':3,  'sequence':3},
    {'claim':111, 'diagnosis':4, }]

df = pd.DataFrame(things)
df
```

I've been wracking my brain on this for days, and any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cumsum` count number of how many `NaN` before that row  , then adding up with `ffill`

```
s1=df['sequence'].isnull().groupby(df['claim']).cumsum()
df['sequence']=s1+df.groupby('claim')['sequence'].ffill()
df
Out[145]: 
    claim  diagnosis  sequence
0     100          1       1.0
1     100          2       1.0
2     100          3       2.0
3     100          4       3.0
4     105          1       1.0
5     105          2       2.0
6     105          3       2.0
7     105          4       3.0
8     111          1       1.0
9     111          2       2.0
10    111          3       3.0
11    111          4       4.0
```